# Why subshell can't catch signal from parent shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got 2 shell scripts:

```
# subshell.sh
trap "echo Caught SIGTERM" 15
echo $$
sleep 100000

# parent.sh
setsid sh subshell.sh &
pid=$!
echo "sid=$pid"
sleep 2
# This won't work!
kill -15 -$pid
```

The main purpose is to send SIGTERM to subshell and all its children. After googling for a while (there is a tricky problem of how bash handles signal), I choose `setsid` to create a new session and sending the signal used `-pid`. However, the message won't be printed although `pid` is correct. If I manually execuate `kill -15 -$pid`, this can work. So how can I send a signal to the subshell?

Comment: Hint: `sleep` is a blocking operation.

Comment: You mean subshell is blocking on sleep so that it can't catch the signal? But when I manually execute the kill command outside these scripts, it does work

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I managed to make this work by creating another subshell..., and then call `kill -15 -$pid` inside that subshell. Still don't know why parent shell can't do this